# How to query for all direct subclasses in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I have `A`, `B` and `C` as classes related by the transitive property `isSubClassOf`.
So `A isSuclassOF B` and `B isSubClassOf C`. So by inference we have `A isSubClassOf C`.

My question: How can I write a SPARQL query to just return back for each Class its direct only subclass  number. for example

```
A    0 
B    1
C    1
```

Comment: SPARQL does not make the inference for you, so if you ask for `?x :rdfs:subClassOf ?y`, you will not get `?x = A, ?y = C` as an answer.

Comment: @scozy in fact that depends on which SPARQL engine you use. Some configurations do support this type of inference by default.

Comment: Also, even if the SPARQL engine does not do reasoning, the relation `A isSubClassOf C` is not necessarily inferred by the reasoner. It may instead be explicitly present in the dataset you're querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the standard SPARQL language, you can do this by querying for those subclasses where no other subclass exists "in between", like so:

```
 SELECT ?directSub ?super 
 WHERE { ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?super .
         FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?otherSub rdfs:subClassOf ?super. 
                             ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSub .
                             FILTER (?otherSub != ?directSub)
         }
 }
```

If you want to count the number of subclasses, you will need to adapt the above query using the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` operators.

Many SPARQL engines offer some shortcuts for querying direct subclasses, however. For example in Sesame, when querying programmatically, you can disable inferencing for the duration of the query by setting a boolean property on the `Query` object to `false`. It also offers an additional reasoner which can be configured on top of a datastore and which allows you to query using a "virtual" property, `sesame:directSubClassOf` (as well as `sesame:directType` and `sesame:directSubPropertyOf`).

Other SPARQL engines have similar mechanisms.

Comment: This query gives a right answer. But suppose a class without subclasses, hwo can i get 0 as answer for this class?

Comment: I thought subClassOf is also reflexive, so you also should add checks `?directSub != ?super` and `?otherSub!= ?super`