# PROTEGE: Get direct subclass with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

It seems using `rdfs:subClassOf` would return **ALL** subclasses in every level of a class.
 how should i get only **direct** subclasses of a class?

BTW protege does not accept [length path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypath-arbitrary-length) in its sparql query tab so for example `rdfs:subClassOf+` is not allowed

Comment: *"It seems using rdfs:subClassOf would return ALL subclasses in every level of a class"* - that's not true. 1) In your example query, you have to assign the superclass from which you want to get the subclasses. 2) as long as no reasoning is enabled (which is the case in Protege), SPARQL returns exactly the asserted subclass relations in the data

Comment: Also not true is the last statement, latest Protege supports full SPARQL 1.1 - I don't know which version you use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010739/7879193

Comment: @StanislavKralin  Ok, I didn't see that Snap SPARQL is used. Then it's clear why all subclass relations are returned. If no reasoning is necessary, I'd simply use the default SPARQL plugin of Protege. Otherwise, the question for direct subclasses is a duplicate, e.g. answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699246/how-to-query-for-all-direct-subclasses-in-sparql)

Comment: I am using protege 5.2 and it does not support length path. As @Stanislav Kralin stated , protege run snap sparql that does not support full sparql syntax

Comment: @alex, go to the *SPARQL Query* tab, then choose *Window > Reset selected tab to default state*, then use `rdfs:subClassOf`.

Comment: @UninformedUser To the best of my knowledge the latest Protege doesn't support the full SPARQL spec. There are two implementations of SPARQL that I know of in Protege: the SPARQLTab and the Snap SPARQL plugin. The SPARQLTab doesn't support reasoning. But (I think this is what you were thinking of) the Snap SPARQL plugin does. That's one of many reasons I usually use the Snap SPARQL plugin. But Snap SPARQL is far from complete. It doesn't support INSERT or DELETE. It doesn't support having wildcards for the predicate, and several other misc. features

Comment: I strongly recommend Protege users use Snap SPARQL. It is superior to the SPARQL Tab in many ways. Besides supporting reasoning you can add data (using CONSTRUCT) with Snap SPARQL. The reason you don't see Snap SPARQL is it is a plugin. You have to load it from the menu of plugins. When you load the plugin then you can go to Window>Views>Query Views>Snap SPARQL and add the Snap SPARQL view to an existing tab. I usually add mine to the DL Query tab.